# How to combine multiple video webRTC mediaStreamTrack at ffmpeg / ffmpegwasm

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webrtc, sip, freeswitch

I'm attempting to combine or mix multiple video tracks into a single mediaStreamTrack, or a mediaStream, I don't want to utilize Canvas as it's not readily available across multiple platforms [mobile devices, react native, etc]

Is there such a possibility through some library of sorts?

I found this but am really uncertain: https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!